# Creating a sequence column to get the Order based on the Date Time and Event

Tags: r

I am trying to create a column to determine the order of the food consumption to know when is the start and end of a Meal. So that I can create a group based on the meals and know what they had.

Current Frame

```
   Name        DateTime   Food Water  Extra       TimeofMeal        Event
1  Alex 27/9/2020 10:25  Apple  Null   Null  27/9/2020 10:25 Start Eating
2  Alex 27/9/2020 10:50   Null   100   Null             Null         Null
3  Alex 27/9/2020 11:05   Null   100   Null             Null         Null
4  Alex 27/9/2020 13:30 Yogurt  Null   Null  27/9/2020 13:30 Start Eating
5   Tom 1/10/2020 10:28 Orange   200   Null 1/10/2020  10:28 Start Eating
6   Tom 1/10/2020 10:30   Null  Null  Candy             Null         Null
7   Tom 1/10/2020 10:40   Null   100   Null             Null         Null
8  Eric 4/10/2020 20:25 Cherry  Null   Null  4/10/2020 20:25 Start Eating
9  Eric 4/10/2020 20:35   Null   100   Null             Null         Null
10 Eric 5/10/2020 10:00  Apple  Null   Null  5/10/2020 10:00 Start Eating
11 Eric 5/10/2020 12:35  Guava  Null   Null  5/10/2020 12:35 Start Eating
12 Eric 5/10/2020 12:40   Null  Null Yogurt             Null         Null
13 Eric 5/10/2020 12:45   Null   300   Null             Null         Null
```

Desired Output for now

```
   Name        DateTime   Food Water  Extra       TimeofMeal        Event Meal
1  Alex 27/9/2020 10:25  Apple  Null   Null  27/9/2020 10:25 Start Eating    1
2  Alex 27/9/2020 10:50   Null   100   Null             Null         Null    1
3  Alex 27/9/2020 11:05   Null   100   Null             Null         Null    1
4  Alex 27/9/2020 13:30 Yogurt  Null   Null  27/9/2020 13:30 Start Eating    2
5   Tom 1/10/2020 10:28 Orange   200   Null 1/10/2020  10:28 Start Eating    1
6   Tom 1/10/2020 10:30   Null  Null  Candy             Null         Null    1
7   Tom 1/10/2020 10:40   Null   100   Null             Null         Null    1
8  Eric 4/10/2020 20:25 Cherry  Null   Null  4/10/2020 20:25 Start Eating    1
9  Eric 4/10/2020 20:35   Null   100   Null             Null         Null    1
10 Eric 5/10/2020 10:00  Apple  Null   Null  5/10/2020 10:00 Start Eating    2
11 Eric 5/10/2020 12:35  Guava  Null   Null  5/10/2020 12:35 Start Eating    3
12 Eric 5/10/2020 12:40   Null  Null Yogurt             Null         Null    3
13 Eric 5/10/2020 12:45   Null   300   Null             Null         Null    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment the count by 1 whenever you encounter `'Start Eating'`.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
           group_by(Name) %>%
           mutate(Meal = cumsum(Event %in% 'Start Eating'))
result
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, Meal := cumsum(Event %in% 'Start Eating'), Name]
```